# Navigation bar hiding partially works after upgradation

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, navigation-key

I have recently upgraded from WP8.1 to W10M. After upgradation navigation bar does not hide when I swipe from the bottom of the screen for a the most of the apps but when I do so for Adobe Reader, Office apps and Edge browser it works. Any solution? My phone's L535DS running november update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the fact that Windows 10 mobile was a little bit buggy at that minute (build 10586) . Now I have updated on build 14393.448 and it resolved my problem. Now I can hide navigation bar for all the apps. If someone else is suffering from same problem then please do upgrade your phone to the latest build of windows 10 mobile and the problem wil be resolved.